# How to get a link in a structure of multiple <div id> and <div class> elements in java

Tags: java, html

[image]first of all, im a newbie, coding since max 2 months and this is my first question, bc i cant believe this is impossible, but i cant find the solution after googling. I hope i can get help here.I have the following problem. I want to extract a link(marked) out of a construct of div ids and div classes(marked), which i cant just easily access via the source code of a website. In the source code there is just a div id opened and closed (the id react-root), where actually the needed data is (found it via inspect element). I m googling since 10h+ and just cant get a code snippet which gives me desired link in java. I already tried some stuff with jsoup.:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HTMLParserExample1 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document doc;
    try {

        // need http protocol
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.challengermode.com/teams/fb475ef0-d9c8-e811-bce7-000d3a214d8f/members").get();

        var x = doc.getElementById("react-root");

        // get page title
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("title : " + title);

        // get all links
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            // get the value from href attribute
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: While writing my answer I see that your code is looking pretty good. What is missing actually? How does it behave, and how do you want it to behave?

Answer (score 0):

So if you like to use JSoup for processing your data, have a look at the chapters under Extracting Data:

- [DOM Navigation](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) (low level but extremely flexible)
- [Selector Syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) (extremely efficient)

If you want to change to other libraries, DOM, XPath and CSS Selectors should be good keywords to lookup.

Edit: In your code I can see you already tried parts of each. Stick with the doc.select() call but just focus on the string you have in there. [Check CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to find out they can do an awful lot.

Comment: I cant very much further than what i have. Even with ur provided links i cant do much, im probably not enougn into it yet to understand what is happening.  could you give me an example, how to "open" a div id in an doctype html and look for the links deeper in it? Maybe my descrition of the problem is bad to clarify what my problem is. I am sorry.

Oh but thanks for ur fast answer, much appreciated!

Comment: I do not use JSoup myself, so all I could do is read out the documentation for you. Maybe you want to post the examples you tried and the (insatisfactory) response you got.

Comment: I cant post any exnamples anymore, i raised the white flag to this ^^ I guess, i cant add another picture, but in the source code there is nothing after react-root. I cant expand it like you can see in "Inspect element". Probably thats the reason, why i cant get to it, because its just not in the html source code i get by the link i inserted. Any ideas maybe how i could get to the content in react-root? (I hate this front end crap^^)